# I am a new user of Mongo Db, please let me know the difference in executing both queries

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Hi I found that the output of the two queries was same, but I want to know is there any difference in executing the query.

First:

```js
 db.collectionname.find({}).pretty()
```

Second:

```js
db.offers.find().pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between these two queries.

1. db.collectionname.find({}).pretty()

   You are not giving any query params here so the results are same like
   db.collectionname.find().pretty()

Answer (score 0):

In short: Both function in the same way.

1) `db.collectionname.find({})`

Here you are not specifying any query parameters and its just an empty document `{}` so it will return you all the documents present in the collection

2) `db.offers.find()`

Here you didn't specify any queries. So it need not even look at the parameters, it will just print you all the documents in the collection. `find()` short form of `find({})`